# What line of code do I have that is making the trail on my circle everytime it moves?

Tags: processing

```
int xPos = 100;    //variable
int yPos = 100;    //variable
void setup() {
  size(400,300); 
  background(0);
  noStroke();
  frameRate(40);  // will make the circles fade in/out slower 
}

void draw() {
 ellipse(xPos,yPos,20,20);
  //background(0);
   fill(0,3); //how fast the stars fadein/out
  rect(0,0, width, height);// Makes the stars fade in/out and fades the trail

  fill(255);  // makes the circle color white
  ellipse(random(width), random(height),3, 3); //draws the blinking stars
}

void keyPressed() 
{
    if (keyCode == UP) {
    yPos--;
     }
    else if (keyCode == DOWN) {
          yPos++;
        }
    else if (keyCode == LEFT) {
         xPos--;
       }
      else  if (keyCode == RIGHT) {
         xPos++;
    }else{
     println("Wrong key"); //prints "Wrong key" in console anytime a different key than keyCode is pressed
    }
}
```

Why is there  a trail following my circle, what line of code makes it do that? I just want to know what kind of code makes it do that because I have no clue.

Comment: Hi, i think you should add appropriate tags (like `c++` and etc. giving information on what technologies are you using). Also i think you should use title of the question to give a brief summary on your problem and then in description of the question add detailed description on what you are trying to do and what problems you are having.

Comment: @komron Please note the [tag:processing] tag. Processing is a language, and the code in the question is a valid [mcve] in Processing.

Comment: @KevinWorkman https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ -- please read a section about titles

Comment: @komron I'm not sure what your point is? Also note that I'm not OP, but this question seems fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

You're drawing a black transparent background here:

```
fill(0, 3); //how fast the stars fadein/out
rect(0, 0, width, height);// Makes the stars fade in/out and fades the trail
```

The first line sets the color to a black, transparent color, and the second color draws a rectangle over the whole window with that color. Since it's transparent, you'll still see what was previously drawn, but it'll get a little bit darker every frame.

Comment: So the fill code sets the color to a black transparent color and the rect draws a rectangle  over the whole window with the fill color?

Comment: @Alex Yeah, that's exactly right. Try experimenting: change it to something like `fill(0)` to draw a fully black background, or change it to `fill(255, 0, 0, 3)` to draw a red transparent background.